# Why is VIM not detecting my coffescript filetype?

Tags: vim, coffeescript

I'm trying to use the vim-coffee-script plugin https://github.com/kchmck/vim-coffee-script  but its not detecting a test file as a coffeescript filetype.  However when I do it manually

```
:set ft=coffee
```

it works.  What's going on?

.vimrc and test.coffee  https://gist.github.com/911087

Comment: Did you install the ftdetect part of the plugin as well? coffee.vim is the part that does this, as you can see: `autocmd BufNewFile,BufRead *.coffee set filetype=coffee`

Comment: Thanks! figured it out though..  it was added as a git submodule, so everything was present, but ftdetect wasn't getting loaded. The question was more along the lines of, why wasn't it getting loaded..  but now it is.    Thanks

Answer (score 21, accepted):

I figured it out..  I had to force reloading of the filetype by setting

```
filetype off
filetype on
```

Specifically, I had to do this AFTER running

```
syntax on
```

This is mostly explained in the pathogen readme

http://www.vim.org/scripts/script.php?script_id=2332

Comment: Huh. I don't use pathogen, but that seems odd. If you just dump all of those files into the right directories, it'll work all by itself, no need for any vimrc trickery.

Comment: Dunno what to say..  its certainly something subtle..  but I git submoduled the vim-coffee-script repo, and it didn't work..  with that change it did.    That said, its probably a bug in my previous .vimrc configuration that I never had to deal with before...

Comment: @Jefromi I just switched from Pathogen to Vundle and saw the *introduction* of this bug.  Using noli's solution fixed the bug for me.

Comment: @noli bro... saved my sanity... I almost switch to sublime/textmate/alternative... (just kidding) but seriously... thanks!

Answer (score 11):

Noli's solution worked for me *sometimes*.  At other times or for other filetypes, it broke.  This was infuriating me.

**The solution** is to move `syntax enable` to the bottom of vimrc.

**Explanation**: Following noli's logic a little further, I checked out the [pathogen docs on Github](https://github.com/tpope/vim-pathogen).  One thing caught my eye

```
execute pathogen#infect()
syntax on
filetype plugin indent on
```

Everything is turned on **after** plugins are installed.  I noticed this wasn't the case in my vimrc, so I moved `syntax` and `filetype` to the bottom of my vimrc.  Problem solved (so far)

Comment: Thanks, super helpful. I had to do BOTH your solution and noli's solution to get it to work. Specifically, I had to include `filetype off` just before `filetype plugin indent on`.

Comment: For me this started happening after I switched to Vundle. I realized the `syntax` and `filetype` lines were before all the `Bundle` lines, so I moved them to after and things started working again.

Comment: Eric Hu's solution worked for me too. I didn't have to move `syntax on` all the way to the bottom, moving it to the line after `filetype plugin indent on` was sufficient.

Answer (score 4):

I tried all the proposed solutions here, but no one worked for me. The solution that worked for me is to add the following snippit to the `~/.vimrc` file

```
syntax on
filetype on
au BufNewFile,BufRead *.coffee set filetype=coffee
```

and problem solved.

Comment: Re. that `au`-tocommand - the thing is that [`vim-coffee-script` should do this for you](https://github.com/kchmck/vim-coffee-script/blob/master/ftdetect/coffee.vim) - there _should_ be no need to add this. However.., I found that inserting it into my `.vimrc` before a `:autocmd!` line didn't help one bit; but inserting after it, did!. Then removing that `:autocmd!` line altogether instead, _also_ fixed it for me - I have no idea hat that line was meant to do, but I have seen no ill effects from its removal so far.