# CoffeeScript snippets not triggering in vim?

Tags: vim, coffeescript, snipmate

I am frequent user of `JS` and my specific snippets are placed at `~/.vim/after/snippets/javascript/_.snippets` which work fine. Recently i moved to coffeescript but i am not able to define custom snippets of my own. I have tried

```
.vim/after/snippets/coffee/_.snippets
.vim/after/snippets/coffee/coffee.snippets
```

I like to use my own snippets but considering [vim-snippets Coffee snippets](https://github.com/honza/vim-snippets/tree/master/snippets/coffee) I find that second case should work which is not.

> File extention that i am using is `.coffee` and the snippet is as shown below

```
snippet log
  console.log ${0}
```

Am i doing something wrong ?

Comment: 1. What is the output of `:set syntax?` in a coffeescript buffer? 2. You are supposed to indent your snippet with a `<Tab>` and only a `<Tab>`.

Comment: @romainl the snippets are using <TAB> only, might have missed here. The output from `:set syntax` is `syntax=`

Answer (score 0):

Okay so i figured out the problem. First install `kchmck/vim-coffee-script` using `vundle` that would be

```
Plugin 'kchmck/vim-coffee-script'
```

Once done I had to reload filetype using

```
filetype off
filetype plugin indent on
syntax on
```

The above issue was found from [This SF answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5602767/why-is-vim-not-detecting-my-coffescript-filetype)

Once that is done, check the output for `set syntax`, if that returns `coffee` then everything is configured and the snippets should start working fine.